# How to Draw a Parse tree contains multiple statements in if condition?

Tags: parsing, if-statement, context-free-grammar, parse-tree, regexp-grammars

I want to draw a parse tree have multiple statements if the condition is true, and multiple statements if the condition is false.

I know how to draw for 1 statement.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the syntactic element of a `block` or `statement-list`that may consist of multiple statements but also may be used as a statement.

In your diagram statement would expand to a block and that then contains the statements.

Comment: What if the parse tree is Abstract Parse tree? which cannot have blocks?

Comment: i think that is impossible, because that would render your language useless, since it only can have one stement.